# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: absolute file name in pack200

Tags: java

I wanted to try to run pack200 tool on my jar file, which is getting huger and huger and there's no reliable tool to remove the 90% of unused `.class` files from it.

I get this error:

```
C:\MyDirectory\programing\java\AutoClient>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\pack200.exe" -r AutoClient_packed.jar AutoClient.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: absolute file name /
        at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.Package.fixupFileName(Package.java:881)
        at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.Package.access$100(Package.java:63)
        at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.Package$File.<init>(Package.java:762)
        at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.PackerImpl$DoPack.readFile(PackerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.PackerImpl$DoPack.run(PackerImpl.java:484)
        at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.PackerImpl.pack(PackerImpl.java:98)
        at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.Driver.main(Driver.java:313)
```

It's really awkward that even official tools crash with random exceptions, just as the unofficial ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you consult [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/java/util/jar/pack/Package.java#865), you can see that the error occurs when your filename starts with a `/`

After tracing the code a bit it appears that the names are sourced from [this method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/java/util/jar/pack/PackerImpl.java#609).

I'm not sure what files your JARs have, but it would appear that either you have an entry whose sole name is `/`, or you have an entry whose name is the value of `File.separatorChar`, and that is being converted to a `/` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/java/util/jar/pack/Utils.java#225)

Comment: Does NetBeans, Ant or Maven produce such JAR files?

Comment: You can try opening the JAR using Java's JarFile and listing all the entries. I wouldn't imagine any of those applications would produce such a file on purpose - it's a very 'invalid' filename as far as filenames go